# Open a file with Microsoft Word

Tags: firefox, playonlinux, microsoft-word

I have Word installed with PlayOnLinux (front-end and helper scripts for WINE).  I'd like to be able to select "open with" when downloading a .doc file with Firefox and open it quickly as can be done with LibreOffice.

I found from the `.desktop` file that the command to run Word is `/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2010"`.  However, when trying to add a new program I'm not able to give it a command-line, just an executable with no parameters.

Is this even possible?

Comment: what does "I'm not able to give it a command-line" mean?

Comment: When you add a program in the firefox dialogue, you either choose from a list or navigate to the executable yourself.  There are no parameters you can choose.

Comment: You could put the appropriate commands in a script, make that script executable, and then select that script in the firefox open with menu. That would get around the problem of not being able to select command-line parameters.

Comment: Thanks!  Can I have a little help as to specifics there?  I'm not too good with bash.

Comment: Yes, please see my answer; it should be what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to place any command-line options in a script (as below) and then select that script through the `firefox` menu. However, it is critical you include `"$@"` so that the file(s) passed from `firefox` will actually be opened. Otherwise, just a blank document would be opened. As an example, this is the sort of wrapper script that you use:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Word 2010" Z:"$@"
```

It is critical to include the `Z:` or the document will not be found by `wine` or its equivalent, as the `Z:` is a symlink to your filesystem.

I also tried this with `WordViewer` in `Wine` and it worked with the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash
wine /home/mike/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Office/OFFICE11/WORDVIEW.EXE Z:"$@"
```

If you just wanted `Libreoffice`, you would instead use in the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

libreoffice --writer "$@"
```

There is further detailed information [in this useful article](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1940522) if you also wish to associate various file types with Microsoft Word 2010, as also discussed in this question:

- [How to set MS Word 2010 as default application for all docx and other types?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/147225/how-to-set-ms-word-2010-as-default-application-for-all-docx-and-other-types)

Create a new text file, copy the contents of the first script (which is what you said you want) and make it executable. Then you can select the script through the firefox menu, as below:

[image]